# Mount and Unmount trigger Desktop environment crash

Tags: linux, mount, fedora, crash

I'm posting this question here, but is also available on [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/116795/mount-and-unmount-trigger-desktop-environment-crash/).

I'm running an up-to-date Fedora 27 on my laptop. Since a couple of days, every time I plug in or unmount a removable device (USB Drive, SD card or Hard Drive), it makes my desktop environment reset and closes my session, jumping me back to the login screen.

`journalctl -e`'s output (run right after a crash) consists in a lot of lines, some of which are in bold. Here is the beginning of the bold section of the output, but I can provide the full output if needed.

```
Object Clutter.Clone (0x56127655f8d0), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
gnome-shell[2701]: Object Clutter.Clone (0x56127655f8d0), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2701]: == Stack trace for context 0x561274cd5170 ==
A lot of stuff here...
```

`dmesg`'s output shows some errors involving my video card (which is a NVidia GTX 960M):

```
[drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
[drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
rfkill: input handler disabled
nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-a2132636-974c-cba4-5912-ecb030e4238f) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-a2132636-974c-cba4-5912-ecb030e4238f) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you running the nvidia proprietary drivers or nouveau? Does the crash report helper offer to file a bug, and if so, what is that bug?

Comment: @mattdm I never actually explicitly installed the proprietary driver, but `lsmod` doesn't show any `nouveau`

Comment: Apparently, this seems to be due to a bug in `places` extension for `gnome-shell`. The bug is issued [here][https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/issues/48]. I'll do some more test and try to see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I discovered that the process triggering the shutdown was indeed one of the builtin extensions of `gnome-shell`, in particular the `places` one. The faulty package is `gnome-shell-extension-places-menu`, and the fix for that is already in the upcoming update of the package.

Until the update happens, I managed to solve it by doing the following:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
mv placeDisplay.js placeDisplay.js.old
wget https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/raw/master/extensions/places-menu/placeDisplay.js
```

Be aware that the location of the extensions might be  in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, if it has been installed locally.

Reference of the bug can be found [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/issues/48).